# How can I highlight duplicate row-based cells in two columns?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

Trying to highlight duplicate row-based cells in Google Sheets. What is the most simple formula I could use to do this?

I've tried using `VLOOKUP` and `COUNTIF`, but maybe I'm using them incorrectly.  Some duplicate cells are being highlighted and some are not. I've cleared formatting after every try.

I've been using:

```
=countif(F:F,G1)
```

and

```
=EQ(VLOOKUP(F1, G:G, 1, FALSE), F1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If selecting Columns F and G and a CF formula rule of:

```
=$H1
```

does not suit then either I have misunderstood or you have Text/Number/space formatting issues so could try:

```
=text($F1,"#")=text($G1,"#")
```

instead - if you prefer to leave the formatting as is.

Where the status is binary (either duplicate or not duplicate) just one CF rule may be adequate for both states, since 'standard' fill (of the whole range) may serve instead of another rule.

Comment: I think this was it. It wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but it highlighted matching cells in the row. I guess I'll study it to see how to have it highlight the non-matching cells.

Answer (score -1):

I think you might be going for this: `=eq(countif(F:F, G1), 1)`

Comment: This formula still gives me random cells that are highlighted. If it helps, the cells are a combination of words and numbers (e.g. 2 bottles, etc.), but I made sure that the words are the exact same and the only thing that changes when looking at rows are the numbers.

Comment: By itself this shouldn't be highlighting at all, but just yielding a "TRUE" or "FALSE". Selecting the column and then choosing the "Conditional Formatting...", you should then be able to set "Format cells if..." to "Text is exactly" and enter "FALSE" (or "TRUE", depending on which ones you want to highlight... or you can add a rule for both), and set the highlight color accordingly.

So do you mean rather that you get seemingly random "FALSE" or "TRUE" results (i.e. you get "FALSE" when you really do have a unique row, or "TRUE" when you do not)?